# Bot Discord python deleting message only of one person

Tags: python, bots, discord, message

I'm programming a bot for discord and trying to delete messages but only the one of the bots since I'm doing some commands that make him spam quite a lot.
So what I've found works well to bulk delete would be

```
    @bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def purge(ctx,msglimit : int):
    deleted = await bot.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=msglimit)
    await bot.say("Cleared **{}** Messages".format(len(deleted)))
```

but the documentation shows this command

```
def is_me(m):
    return m.author == client.user

    deleted = await client.purge_from(channel, limit=100, check=is_me)
    await client.send_message(channel, 'Deleted {} message(s)'.format(len(deleted)))
```

But i can't really guet it to work if someone has an idea

Comment: Does the bot have the proper perms? Did the client user post any message within the msglimit? "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about your problem, please be specific.

Comment: Bot has all the permissions as he can delete all the messages but i want the second code to work as to delete only the bots messages

Comment: How is the second code not working? A traceback (post it)? The messages doesn't delete (post a [mcve])? There isn't much to go on, the code should work if you use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_me(m):
    return m.author == bot.user

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def purge(ctx):
    deleted = await bot.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, check=is_me)
    await bot.say("Cleared **{}** Messages".format(len(deleted)))
```

This deletes a certain number of messages (100 by default).

The `purge_from` method takes an argument called `check` which is a function that takes a message and returns whether the message should be deleted.

The `is_me` function will return true if the message author is the bot.

Which means that calling `purge` will delete the bot that picked up this command. If you need the bot to delete a different user's messages, you will need to change the condition.